# Loop integrals in perturbative RG

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics

I am trying to follow David Tong's notes on statistical field theory, and I am stuck on the derivation of the RG flow equations.  Specifically, Equation 3.37 in [these notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/sft/three.pdf).

We are dealing with the standard $\phi^4$ theory, and $\phi$ is separated into a long-wavelength part, $\phi^-$, and a short-wavelength part, $\phi^+$.  We then integrate out $\phi^+$ to obtain an effective theory for $\phi^-$ on a longer lengthscale.

To find out how the $\phi^4$ term flows under RG, we consider a 2nd order process which gives rise to Eq 3.37:

$\int d^d q_1 d^2 q_2 G_0(q_1) G_0(q_2) \delta^d (\mathbf{k}_1 + \mathbf{k}_2 + \mathbf{q}_1 + \mathbf{q}_2)\delta^d (\mathbf{k}_3 + \mathbf{k}_4 - \mathbf{q}_1 - \mathbf{q}_2)$

where $\mathbf{k}_{1,2,3,4}$ are external momenta, and the integrals over $q_1$ and $q_2$ are only over short-wavelength momenta: $\int_{\Lambda/\zeta}^{\Lambda}d^d q_{1,2}$.

In the last line of Eq 3.37, the integral over $q_2$ is done and the delta function is used to replace it by $\mathbf{q}_2 \rightarrow \mathbf{k}_3 + \mathbf{k}_4 + \mathbf{q}_1$, resulting in

$\int d^d q G_0(q) G_0(|\mathbf{k}_1 + \mathbf{k}_2 + \mathbf{q}|) \delta^d (\mathbf{k}_1+\mathbf{k}_2+\mathbf{k}_3+\mathbf{k}_4)$

where $q\equiv q_1$.

My confusion is: since the integral over $q_2$ is only over the short-wavelength momenta, it seems that the integral over $q_2$ should only give a non-zero result if $\Lambda/\zeta<|\mathbf{k}_3 + \mathbf{k}_4 + \mathbf{q}_1|<\Lambda$.  Thus, the last line should only be true for some $\mathbf{q}$ where this condition is satisfied, while zero for others.  What's going on here?

Comment: I am reminded of Kerson Huang's comment about the renormalization group analysis with a hard cutoff:  "The development... is of the nature of a fable[;] it is not really true, but illustrates a point."